# multiple rest api calls to third party is giving time out issue

Tags: rest, web-services

we are getting time out issue while doing multiple restful api calls to a third party.
The scenario(giving an example) is that we need to call one restful api(say REST1) to get all the employee IDs and for every employee ID we need to call another restful api(say REST2) to get the employee detail.Since we are having around 10000 employee IDs we have to make 10000 calls to REST2 which is resulting in time out issue.

The current JDK version being used is JDK6. Please suggest if there is any good approach to handle this situation.

Comment: which tool are you using to make the calls ? Did you try adding a wait time in between requests ? This is going to increase your time of execution but could reduce the load on the server and give you a proper response

Comment: I have not added any wait time in the code between the requests as already its taking more time to load the UI and we have integrated Jersey framework.Well the problem does not exist any more as we got a Rest APi which provides both employee ID and their details .Thanks for the suggestion.